# How can I share a struct with pointers between processes in C?

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

I'm trying to put a file in a struct but I'm having problems sharing the memory as I can access the fields in the created process where the mapping happens but cannot access the arrays(can only access the int) in the other processes. I tried a lot of different things but the way I present next is the one that makes more sense to me as I'm allocating memory the right way with shmget.

For clarity: The only thing that is being shared is the integer lim_thread. The other fields are in a area of memory that I can not access. Why? 
As I see the pointers are pointing to a region of memory that is shared.

configs.txt:

```
Threads = 5
Domains = uc.pt; edu
LocalDomain = so.local
NamedPipeEstatisticas = statistics
```

struct:

```
typedef struct configs
{
    int lim_thread;
    char (*valid_domains)[MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE]; //max size for valid domains
    char *domain;
    char *stat_pipe;
    sem_t sem;
} CONFIGS;
```

main.c:

```
/*Shared memory for configs*/
CONFIGS *_configs;
int _shmid_configs;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t config_pid; //will hold the configuration process id

    _shmid_configs = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(CONFIGS), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    _configs = shmat(_shmid_configs, NULL, 0);
    /*Semaphores*/
    sem_init( &( _configs->sem), 1, 0);
//initializes processes
    if( ( config_pid = fork() ) < 0) {
        perror("Failed creating configuration manager process");
        num_forks++;
    }
    else if( config_pid == 0 ) {
        init_config();
        exit(0);
    }
    sem_wait(&(_configs->sem));

/////////////////////////DEBUG////////////////////////////////
    printf("%d\n", _configs->lim_thread);
    printf("%s\n", *(_configs->valid_domains+1));
    printf("%s\n", _configs->domain);
    printf("%s\n", _configs->stat_pipe);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return 0;
}
```

configs.c

```
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1000

int init_config() {

    FILE *fp;
    char domains[MAX_LINE_SIZE], line[MAX_LINE_SIZE], *saveptr, *aux_char;
    int count = 0, aux;
    int temp_shmid;

    if( ( fp = fopen( "./configs.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open configs.txt");
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf( fp,"Threads = %d\n", &(_configs->lim_thread)); 

    //To start reading "Domains = "
    fscanf(fp, "Domains = ");

    fgets(domains, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp);
    domains[strlen(domains) -1] = '\0';

    //counts the number of domains
    for(aux = 0; aux < strlen(domains); aux++) {
        if( domains[aux] == ';' ) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    //creates shared memory for the valid domains
    temp_shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (count+1) * sizeof( char[MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE]), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    _configs->valid_domains = shmat( temp_shmid, NULL, 0);

    //copies all the data to the struct
    strcpy( *(_configs->valid_domains), strtok_r(domains, "; ", &saveptr) );
    aux = 1;
    while( ( aux_char = strtok_r( NULL, "; ", &saveptr) ) != NULL) {
        strcpy( *(_configs->valid_domains + aux), aux_char);
        aux++;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "LocalDomain = %s\n", line);
    temp_shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (strlen(line) + 1) * sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT|0660);
    _configs->domain = (char*)shmat(temp_shmid, NULL, 0);
    strcpy(_configs->domain, line);

    fscanf(fp, "NamedPipeEstatisticas = %s\n", line);
    temp_shmid = shmget( IPC_PRIVATE, (strlen(line) +1) * sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT|0660);
    _configs->stat_pipe = (char*)shmat(temp_shmid, NULL, 0);
    strcpy(_configs->stat_pipe, line);


    fclose(fp);

    sem_post( &(_configs->sem));

/////////////////////////DEBUG////////////////////////////////
    printf("%d\n", _configs->lim_thread);
    printf("%s\n", *(_configs->valid_domains+1));
    printf("%s\n", _configs->domain);
    printf("%s\n", _configs->stat_pipe);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't share pointers across process boundaries. That doesn't change even if the pointer is pointing to shared memory. The other process needs to map that shared memory into its address space and it will almost certainly do so at a different virtual address. So you can't give the mapping/address made in one process directly to another process. Each process needs to make its own mapping to the shared memory.

Comment: So what should i do? How can i map the file into shared memory? Isnt there any option for this to work right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kaylum pointed out, each process might map a shared memory block to a different virtual address. Hence pointers cannot be shared, you need to work with offsets.

Allocate a single block of shared memory that you divide in two parts: a table of content and a data area. The table of content consists of variables that contain either a value or (instead of a pointer), the offset between the start of the shared memory block and the start of a data element inside the data area.

Then to obtain the address of a data element a process simply adds its offset to the address of the shared memory block in its address space.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do what you want.  Just do all your `shmget/shmat` in your *main* process/thread *before* you create any threads.

The children will inherit the pointers and the values will be the same for all threads (e.g. the pointers are *global*.  That is, they are *not* using `_thread` and are not in thread local storage).

This works fine.  I've used it in systems with 50+ threads and it works great

Comment: The thing is i only know how many files i want after i open the file and i want the Chile process to do all the work related to that so i cant use the shmget before the cratiob of the pointers

Comment: You can if you think about it.    I think the conceptual problem is conjoining the config read and shm allocations with the process management.  They are different steps.  Call init_config before spawning anything.  It sets up shm areas, stores any per-thread info needed, but does _not_ start threads.  Then create processes [only], based upon what init_config read [and stored away].  Even if you want a "master" process to control children, make this the main thread.  Or, fire all children from the control process, which gets spawned _after_ init_config is called